# Why am I getting this undefined index error?

Tags: codeigniter, php

I'm trying to list the indexes of an array, and it keeps throwing errors in my face.

I am getting this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: sender

Now for some code details:
My print line:

```
<div class="left"><label>Afsender: </label><p><?=$reservation['sender'] . ' (' .     $reservation['email'] . ')'?></p></div></pre>
```

My controller: (using phil sturgeon's template library for CodeIgniter)

```
public function readReservation($id)
{
    $data['reservation'] = $this->reservation_model->getReservation($id);
    $this->template->build('admin/readReservation_view', $data);
}
```

My Model:

```
public function getReservation($id) 
{
    $query = $this->db->where('id', $id)->get('ita_reservations');

    if ($query->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

My sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ita_reservations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `persons` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `time_received` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `confirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

Now what baffles me, is that the same code works elsewhere, but with a different variable name. To increase my confusion, this is the `var_dump` from the line above my print:

> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#42 (10) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1"
>   ["sender"]=> string(7) "Kenneth" ["email"]=> string(17)
>   "zungate@gmail.com" ["date"]=> string(10) "23/05/2013" ["time"]=>
>   string(5) "18:00" ["persons"]=> string(1) "4" ["phone"]=> string(8)
>   "30243681" ["message"]=> string(12) "Ja nemlig ja" ["time_received"]=>
>   string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["confirmed"]=> string(1) "0" } }

The sender index is clearly there, and the array is clearly loaded properly. (All indexes throw errors, not just sender).

What's going on, and what am I missing? Yes, I know I should check for `isset` or `empty`, but it exists, and the page cannot be loaded if the index doesn't exist so checks are kindof moot.

Comment: `$reservation[0]->sender;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object inside an array (see your `var_dump`), so to get the reservation sender you have to use the following:

```
$reservation[0]->sender
```

Or better yet, instead of returning the whole result set from your function, you should only return one row (assuming id's are unique, your query will return only one row anyway):

```
public function getReservation($id) 
{
  $query = $this->db->where('id', $id)->get('ita_reservations');

  if ($query->num_rows > 0) 
  {
    return $query->row();
  }
  else
    return false;
}
```

With this you can use:

```
$reservation->sender
```

Comment: How odd, that fixed it. But that doesn't explain why the exact same code (pretty much) works in a different part of my system.

And that var_dump looks exactly the same, just with fewer elements.

Comment: @KennethLindbergChristensen: Does the other part (where what you describe does work) use a loop, by any chance? in which case, it explains everything

Comment: @KennethLindbergChristensen No it CAN not work if all the codes are same and only variables are different. In future, doing var dump, use `pre` tag. will save you lot of headache while debugging.

Comment: @KennethLindbergChristensen - Well, I can't explain that unless you post that other part of your system. But it is probably what Elias suggests.

Comment: It does not - but I took Mischa's recommendation and used $query->row() instead, and it works perfectly. Thanks  :)

Comment: @KennethLindbergChristensen - glad it works and I hope you understand *why* you were getting that error now.